# Random dns problems when connecting VPN

Tags: dns, vpn

When I connect to my work VPN, I often loose DNS servers (the effect is not immediate). I can't nslookup any name and it causes all kinds of lockups, particularly in the virtual machines I'm running locally.

One thing I've noticed is that /etc/resolv.conf seems corrupted (the 1st is the valid IP of my work DNS):

```
nameserver 666.666.666.666
nameserver or
nameserver is
search mywork.com
nameserver
nameserver
```

Is this a bad configuration of my VPN ?
I use Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know if the syntax of the /etc/resolv.conf file is correct, but I think I solved the DNS problems with the following command to flush the cache after conncet/deconnection of the VPN:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```